# Javascript Promises chain with setTimeout calls not behave as expected

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have the following code to test asynchronous exectution in Javascript, using promises and timeout's:

```
'use strict'
const { promisify } = require('util')

const print = (err, contents) => { 
  if (err) console.error(err)
  else console.log(contents) 
}

const opA = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, 'A')
  }, 500)
}

const opB = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, 'B')
  }, 250)
}

const opC = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, 'C')
  }, 125)
}

const opAProm = promisify(opA)
const opBProm = promisify(opB)
const opCProm = promisify(opC)

opAProm(print).then((res) => opBProm(print).then((res) => opCProm(print)))
```

The result I would expect is this:

```
A
B
C
```

But instead it gets printed just this:

```
A
```

I have looked for a solution and the most similar one I have found is this one although it hasn't help me really:
[Javascript Promises: then()'s aren't synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645610/javascript-promises-thens-arent-synchronous)

So I would like to know how can I solve this, using promises or async/await.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After promisifying something, you shouldn't be *passing it a callback* - rather, only call `.then` on the resulting Promise. If you remove the `print`s from the lines like these:

```
opAProm(print)
```

and instead chain off the Promise directly, it'll work as desired.

```
opAProm().then((resultA) => {
    print(resultA);
    opBProm().then((resultB) => {
        print(resultB);
        opCProm()
            .then((resultC) => {
                print(resultC);
            });
    })
});
```

Or, a better approach:

```
opAProm()
    .then((resultA) => {
        print(resultA);
        return opBProm();
    }).then((resultB) => {
        print(resultB);
        return opCProm();
    })
    .then((resultC) => {
        print(resultC);
    });
```

(or use `async`/`await`)

Otherwise, if you do (like in your original code)

```
opAProm(print)
```

Then the `cb` is inferred to be the function passed - the `cb` for `opA` - which is not connected to the Promise, so further chaining doesn't work. With util's promisify, the callback that the promise replaces should be the final argument of the original function - if you pass it *another* argument in combination, it'll get out of whack. Unless you change the original functions to accept two arguments, which would be really weird, but would "work".

```
const opA = (cb, finalcb) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb(null, 'A')
        finalcb();
    }, 500)
}

const opB = (cb, finalcb) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb(null, 'B')
        finalcb();
    }, 250)
}

const opC = (cb, finalcb) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb(null, 'C')
        finalcb();
    }, 125)
}

const opAProm = promisify(opA)
const opBProm = promisify(opB)
const opCProm = promisify(opC)

opAProm(print)
    .then(() => {
        return opBProm(print);
    }).then(() => {
        return opCProm(print);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Promisify removes the last `callback` function. Meaning, passed `print` method is **useless** here. Instead of that, you will get the result in the `then/resolve` function and print. As @CertainPerformance mentioned, You can either convert to use promise with print in then or use async-await to simplify.

```js
const { promisify } = require("util");

const print = (err, contents) => {
  if (err) console.error(err);
  else console.log(contents);
};

const opA = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, "A");
  }, 500);
};

const opB = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, "B");
  }, 250);
};

const opC = (cb) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, "C");
  }, 125);
};

const opAProm = promisify(opA);
const opBProm = promisify(opB);
const opCProm = promisify(opC);

async function main() {
  const resA = await opAProm();
  console.log(resA);
  const resB = await opBProm();
  console.log(resB);
  const resC = await opCProm();
  console.log(resC);
}
main();
```